# Wavelength of generated X-Rays

Tags: x-rays, particle-accelerators

$$E_{photon} = \frac{hc}\lambda\\
E_{electron} = eV$$

Where h, c, lambda, e and V are Planck's constant, the speed of light, the wavelength of a photon, the charge of an electron and the Voltage in which the electron is accelerated, respectively.

The transfer of energy from the accelerated electron, to the X-ray photon is less than 1% (the majority is transferred as heat to a target metal).

So, why would the equation

$$\lambda = \frac{hc}{eV}$$ hold?

This equation assumes the energies of the X-ray photon and the electron are identical, when in fact, they're not.

Comment: I think this equation holds only for $\lambda_{min} $ , because some (a little amount) of the electrons do transfer their energy entirely to one photon, and that will be the photon with the shortest wave length - but for the majority it isn't true, and so is the formula.

Comment: Makes sense. Sort of like the distribution of velocities in liquids, in that, most won't have high energies but a small amount will--and evaporate.